# Trouble in calculating the size of URL

Tags: android, urlconnection

I want to know the size of the url in order to download the file but its crashing on runtime. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t1;
    private int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        try {


            URL url = new URL("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg");
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            i = conection.getContentLength();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        t1.setText(i + "MB");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all url task done in background,so use Async Task class for this........
Below code ......look like this

```
    class SignInAsyntask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            String result;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

                 // doing all url works.................  
                  return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

                super.onPostExecute(response);


                Log.e("Result", response);

            }
        }
```

and call it onCreate() method look like tis......

```
 new SignInAsyncTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app crashes is because you're accessing the network on the **main thread**. You should make the network call on a **background thread**, using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).